# Merge my custom model with the pretrained default models Yolov5

Tags: python, computer-vision, dataset, object-detection, yolov5

Hi I have a custom model pt file (and dataset) for detecting only toy soldiers, and would like to somehow 'slice' the 'car' class detection the yolov5s.pt model and merge it with my own model, or vice versa.

Is there a way to merge the two models together? I basically want to end up with a model that detects two classes, cars and toy soldiers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to merge two models. But you can train a new model with your custom dataset and 'Car' class from COCO dataset. You can use this tookit for downloading a specific class from COCO
[OID Toolkit](https://github.com/EscVM/OIDv4_ToolKit.git)

```
 python3 main.py downloader -y --classes Car --type_csv train
```

Feel free to ask more doubt. Thanks